# Not able to link the static dependency/library after resolving it using CMake FetchContent module

Tags: cmake

Below piece of code is not working. I want to resolve the dependency called dependency1 using `FetchContent`, which is a static library and link to my target executable. Note the static dependency is a CMake project which is in svn.

Note FetchContent successfully does svn checkout in the SOURCE_DIR at compile-time, but it gives an error when I try to link the executable to the following error on line `target_link_libraries(App1, dependency1)`:

```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "App1," which is not built by this  project.
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

My **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(App1)

include(FetchContent)

message("fetching dependency1")
FetchContent_Declare(
  dependency1
  SVN_REPOSITORY http://............/Dependency1
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(dependency1)

if(NOT dependency1_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(dependency1)
  add_subdirectory(${dependency1_SOURCE_DIR} ${dependency1_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

add_executable (App1 "App1.cpp" "App1.h")

link_directories(${dependency1_BINARY_DIR})

target_link_libraries(App1 dependency1)
```

Thanks to Tsyvarev the above issue is resolved. There was an extra comma which I incorrectly used in targer_link_libraries.

But now when I try to build it is not able to find the static library i.e. "libDependency1.a"

```
Scanning dependencies of target App1
[ 25%] Building CXX object App1/CMakeFiles/App1.dir/App1.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable App1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldependency1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [App1/App1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [App1/CMakeFiles/App1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I added link_directories(${dependency1_BINARY_DIR}) but still it didn't fix the issue.

I somehow able to resolve the issue but not able to fully understand how things work.

The issue got resolved if I use Dependency1 instead of dependency1 in target_link_libraries .

```
target_link_libraries(App1 dependency1) --- Does not work
 target_link_libraries(App1 dependency1)  --- Works
```

In FetchContent declaration I passed name as "dependency1" as I remember "Dependency1" was not working earlier . Note the name of my dependency is Dependency1 (with capital D) . In target_link_libraries I thought it should take the name that I passed to the FetchContent declaration but its very strange.

Comment: You reference FetchContent in this code, but it is not shown. Can you add the code for FetchContent to your post?

Comment: You have extra comma (`,`) in the `target_link_libraries` call. In CMake, comma is an ordinal character, which becomes part of the parameter (See closely the name of the target in the error message).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tsyvarev. I removed comma from targer_link_libraries and it worked but now it is not able to find the library.
"/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldependency1"
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [App1/App1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [App1/CMakeFiles/App1.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: It looks more like your _dependency_ is called `dependency1` but your _target_ is called `Dependency1`. Note that target names are case-sensitive. The `target_link_libraries()` command requires target names, not dependency names.